# Cordova requestFileSystem: wrong calculated free disk space on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, diskspace, cordova-plugins

I have some issue on iOS trying to allocate more than 140 Mbytes with File plugin 1.0.1.

I have 10 giga free on device but a QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR was thrown

Here is the code:

```
var requestBytes = 150 * 1024 * 1024;

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, requestBytes, function(fs) {
    // success callback
}, function (e) {
      // error callback
});
```

I see that the free space calulated in requestFileSystem method of CDVFile.m results always about 144 Mbytes.

Any idea? How is the free space calculated? Are there some limits for iOS apps?

Note that on android I haven't any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug.
I opened an issue that is already merged on master branch

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6872